# Setup a google charts inside a slider

Tags: javascript, charts, slider, google-visualization

I have a two google charts and load in two divs inside a slider. The first chart is shows fine, but the second one is bad, the chart's scale shows over text, and the chart's legend is outside of chart area. See image error
Chart code:

```
    
        
       //Indice de Precios al Consumidor  
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});    
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Año', 'IPC nacional'],
              ['ene-10',  1.9],
              ['feb-10',  2.7],
              ['mar-10',  4.4],
              ['abr-10',  4.9],
              ['may-10',  4.7],
              ['jun-10',  4.6],
              ['jul-10',  6.2],
              ['ago-10',  5.3],
              ['sep-10',  5.4],
              ['oct-10',  7.3],
              ['nov-10',  8.8],
              ['dic-10',  9.2],
              ['ene-11',  8.0],
              ['feb-11',  7.2],
              ['mar-11',  6.7],
              ['abr-11',  7.1],
              ['may-11',  8.3],
              ['jun-11',  9.0],
              ['jul-11',  8.5],
              ['ago-11',  9.7],
              ['sep-11',  9.5],
              ['oct-11',  7.7],
              ['nov-11',  7.3],
              ['dic-11',  8.0],
              ['ene-12',  8.0],
              ['feb-12',  8.8],
              ['mar-12',  8.5],
              ['abr-12',  9.0],
              ['may-12',  7.5],
              ['jun-12',  6.5],
              ['jul-12',  6.4],
              ['ago-12',  6.0],
              ['sep-12',  6.4],
              ['oct-12',  6.5],
              ['nov-12',  6.2],
              ['dic-12',  6.0],
              ['ene-13',  7.7],
              ['feb-13',  7.1],
              ['mar-13',  6.8],
              ['abr-13',  6.3],
              ['may-13',  7.7],
              ['jun-13',  8.3],
              ['jul-13',  7.7],
              ['ago-13',  7.9],
              ['sep-13',  7.4],
              ['oct-13',  6.8],
              ['nov-13',  6.3],
              ['dic-13',  5.7],
              ['ene-14',  5.2],
              ['feb-14',  5.3],
              ['mar-14',  5.1],
              ['abr-14',  4.9],
              ['may-14',  4.8],
              ['jun-14',  6.1],
              ['jul-14',  6.9],
              ['ago-14',  6.7],
            ]);
            var options = {
              title: 'Indice de Precios al Consumidor',
     titleTextStyle: {color: '#333',fontSize:12},
      titlePosition: 'out',
              'width':315,
              'height':322, 
            curveType: 'function',
            //backgroundColor: "#ccc",
            chartArea:{left:30,top:35,right:0,bottom:5,width:'88%',height:'75%'},
        legend: { position: 'none' }  };                    
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);      
          }   
        
         
       //Indice de Precios al Consumidor  
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});    
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Año', 'Tendencia ciclo interanual'],
              ['ene-13',  5.9],
              ['feb-13',  5.9],
              ['mar-13',  5.8],
              ['abr-13',  5.6],
              ['may-13',  5.4],
              ['jun-13',  5.4],
              ['jul-13',  5.4],
              ['ago-13',  5.2],
              ['sep-13',  5.0],
              ['oct-13',  4.6],
              ['nov-13',  4.2],
              ['dic-13',  3.9],
              ['ene-14',  3.8],
              ['feb-14',  3.8],
              ['mar-14',  3.9],
              ['abr-14',  4.0],
              ['may-14',  4.0],
              ['jun-14',  3.8],
              ['jul-14',  3.6],
            ]); 
            var options = {
              title: 'IMAE tendencia-ciclo',
     titleTextStyle: {color: '#333',fontSize:12},
      titlePosition: 'out',
              'width':315,
              'height':322, 
            curveType: 'function',
            //backgroundColor: "#ccc",
            chartArea:{left:30,top:35,right:0,bottom:5,width:'88%',height:'75%'},
        legend: { position: 'none' }  };                    
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));

            chart.draw(data, options);      
          }
```

Slider code:

```
    
            
                        
                    
                      
                
            
                    
                      
                
                
            
        
        
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slider').s3Slider({
                timeOut: 5000
            });
        });
```

Comment: have you tried to redraw the chart when the new slide shows up?

Comment: yes, but still didn't work

Comment: Drawing charts inside hidden divs breaks some internal dimension detection algorithms in the Visualization API, so you have to either draw your charts before instantiating the slider or draw each chart only as it's container first becomes visible.

Comment: How can draw charts before  instantiating the slider or draw each chart only as it's container first becomes visible?